# Proof by induction for a recursive sequence (closed form formula given)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was given the following:

A sequence is defined recursively by a<sub>0</sub> = 0, and, for n>=1, a<sub>n</sub> = 5a<sub>n-1</sub> + 1. Use induction to prove the closed form formula for a<sub>n</sub> is a<sub>n</sub> = (5<sup>n</sup> - 1) / 4.

So far for my proof, all I have is this:

a<sub>n+1</sub> = 5a<sub>n</sub> + 1

=5 ((5n - 1) / 4) + 1

What do I do next? I've forgotten what I'm even trying to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base case: $a_1=\frac{5^1-1}{4}=\frac{5-1}{4}=\frac{4}{4}=1$

Assume $a_n=\frac{5^n-1}{4}$

then $a_{n+1}=5a_n+1=5\frac{5^n-1}{4}+1=\frac{5^{n+1}-5}{4}+1=\frac{5^{n+1}-5+4}{4}=\frac{5^{n+1}-1}{4}$
as was desired.

Answer (score 0):

1) $a_{1}=\frac{(5^1-1)}{4}=1$ - that's ok.

2) $a_{n}=\frac{5^n-1}{4}$

3)$a_{n+1}=5a_{n}+1=5\frac{(5^n-1)}{4}+1=\frac{5^{n+1}-5}{4}+\frac{4}{4}=\frac{5^{n+1}-1}{4}=a_{n+1}$